# Get set of objects within top x% their rating via Django orm

Tags: django, django-orm

Question is regarding annotation and aggregation in Django.

For example I have following model.

```
class Example(models.Model)
    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(min=1, max=10, null=True, blank=True)
```

Where rating is a positive integer from 1 to 10

Goal is to fetch queryset from db that would contain top X % entries according their rating(for example top 20%) and do it in one single queryset without raw sql usage (only by Django ORM).

Database -Postgres.

Dataset might not contain all values from 1 to 10 necessarily. It might be 6,7,3,3,3,4,5 for example easily.

What I do :

```
from django.db.models import FloatField, Max, Min
from django.db.models.functions import Ceil, Floor

def top_x_percent(self, percent: int) -> models.QuerySet:
    """
    Returns top x % of according their rating.
    """
    result = self.aggregate(
        Min('rating', output_field=FloatField()),
        Max('rating', output_field=FloatField()),
    )
    one_percent_value = (result['rating__max'] - result['rating__min']) / 100
    top_range = (
        Ceil(result['rating__max'] - (percent * one_percent_value)),
        Floor(result['rating__max'])
    )
    return self.filter(rating__range=top_range)
```

But it makes 2 querysets

Any ideas how to make it all in one singular neat queryset?

Thank you

Comment: I guess your current code does not really show the `top 20%` in the statistical sense,i.e. percentile. Calculating percentiles needs considering whole data and this can be best achieved by using cronjobs and storing them in a table or in the user model so that you don't have to calculate them each time.